# Removing attachments from the bottom of a Notes Document?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

I have Notes Documents  that have attachments at the bottom of the document(yes I know what causues it).   How do I programaticly remove those attachments without removing attachments that are in fields?

I was hoping to use NotesDoument.Embeeded objects but it does not include file attachments. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Evaluate() (yes, this is one of the few times you want to use it), calling the @AttachmentNames formula to get a list of all attachment in the document.
You can then process the array you get back and compare to the ones you have attached in the rich text fields, and delete the ones you don't want.

I would first get all embedded attachments from the rich text fields, and store the names in a list.
Then I would use @AttachmentNames to get all attachments on the document and put them in another list.
Bot lists should have the file name as the list tag.
You can now very easily loop through the second list using ForAll, and if there is no matching ´list item in the first list, delete the attachment from the document. Use IsElement() to check is a specific list item exists.

Comment: A little messy but sadly it might be the only way.

Comment: Actaully it is @AttachmentNames. What happens if there are multiple files with the same name and one is at the bottom of the document? Which one is the right one? I am not sure this will work. I need to think about this maybe it will work.

Comment: Bruce, you are correct. I don't use Formula that much anymore, I write most of my code in native Lotusscript. :-)

Comment: I think when you have multiples, @AttachmentNames returns an "internal" name like "$ATT0001",

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to remove `Rich Text` fields that are not on the `Form` and remove attachments that are not in the `Rich Text` fields.
To retrieve `Form` fields, you can use `NotesForm` object, which you can access through `NotesDatabase.GetForm` method. If your `Notes Document` does not have a form, than you can retrive fields from default database form, which you can get by using `NotesDocument` from `NotesDatabase.GetDocumentByID("FFFF0004")` and its `$Fields` item. But if your `Form` containts `Computed Sub Forms` than you need to manually check for fields that may be in this `Computed Sub Forms`.
To get all attachments you can use `NotesDocument.Items` with "$FILE" name and use its value to get the name of attachment.
Here is example:

```
'Declarations
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim form As NotesForm
Dim defaultForm As NotesDocument
Dim fields As Variant
Dim rtItems() As NotesRichTextItem
Dim files() As String
Dim fileItem As NotesItem

'Get the database and document here

Set form = db.GetForm(doc.Form(0))

'Get Form fields
If form Is Nothing Then
    Set defaultForm = db.GetDocumentByID("FFFF0004")

    If defaultForm Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub 'Nothing to do
    End If

    fields = defaultForm.~$Fields
Else
    fields = form.Fields
End If

count% = 0

'Get all Rich Text items in document
Forall item In doc.Items
    If item.Type = RICHTEXT% Then
        Redim Preserve rtItems(count%) As NotesRichTextItem
        Set rtItems(count%) = item

        count% = count% + 1
    End If
End Forall

Redim files(0) As String

If count% > 0 Then
    count% = 0

    'Remove Rich Text items that are not in form and get all file names
    Forall rtItem In rtItems
        fieldIndex = Arraygetindex(fields, rtItem.Name)

        If Isnull(fieldIndex) Then
            Call rtItem.Remove
        Elseif Not Isempty(rtItem.EmbeddedObjects) Then
            Forall obj In rtItem.EmbeddedObjects                    
                Redim Preserve files(count%) As String
                files(count%) = obj.Name

                count% = count% + 1
            End Forall
        End If
    End Forall
End If

'Remove all files that are not in Rich Text item
For index = Ubound(doc.Items) To 0 Step -1
    Set fileItem = doc.Items(index)

    If Ucase(fileItem.Name) = "$FILE" Then
        fileIndex = Arraygetindex(files, fileItem.Values(0))

        If Isnull(fileIndex) Then
            fileItem.Remove
        End If
    End If
Next

'Save changes here
```